# Calculated column that ignores row context

Tags: dax

I'm trying to calculate the Total Price per Order number. It specifically needs to be a column, because I'll be needing it for further calculations.

Can someone help me write code that calculates the total per Order Number, instead of line amount as it does now?

[image: Picture of data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a calcualted column, just avoiding any context transition gives a straightforward solution

```
Total Price Per Order =
VAR CurrentOrder = SalesDetail[Order Number]
RETURN
    SUMX (
        FILTER (
            SalesDetail,
            SalesDetail[Order Number] = CurrentOrder
        ),
        SalesDetail[Unit Price] * SalesDetail[Quantity]
    )
```